# Possible to silently monitor Skype group conversation?

Tags: skype

There is a Skype group where people involved in a project discuss technical issues.

Is there a way that I can add another person to this group who will be able to view the conversation, but other group member will not be able to see it (it would not appear on the list of group members)? Something like a silent monitor.

Comment: No;  If you want this ability use something you have more control over.  While Skype might or might not have a backdoor in it.  Its not documented and as of now nobody really has proven it existence in actuality only on leak information that might or might not be true.